# Sed to wrap lines in text file?

Tags: sed

I am a newbie with Sed. I have a bunch of ASCII files containing data that's laid out like so:

```
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:
HR21-100
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:
D12-100
```

All I want to do is fold the lines for "Model-Manufacturer:" like this:

```
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:HR21-100
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:D12-100
```

I tried to use sed since I discovered there are 2 hex values (0xA for \n) after "Model-Manufacturer:"

```
cat myfile| sed -n "/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/p"
```

The output looked like this for my match code:

```
Model-Manufacturer:
HR21-100
Model-Manufacturer:
D12-100
```

This tells me I am on the right track, right? What I cannot figure out is the proper match/replace code to  fold the lines for "Model-Manufacturer:". A attempt with

```
cat myfile| sed "s/[[:xdigit:]]\{3\}//g"
```

completed messed up my file. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cat test.txt
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:
HR21-100
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:
D12-100

$ cat test.txt | sed -e '/:$/N; s/:\n/:/'
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:HR21-100
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:D12-100
```

Here's a break down of each sed command.

```
/:$/N
```

If the input line has a ':' at the end, insert a newline at the end of the pattern space and append the next line of input.

```
s/:\n/:/
```

Replace a ":" followed by a newline with ":", removing the newline.

Comment: great solution! Thank you. Would H (hold) be better instead of N(append)?

Comment: There's no need to utilize the hold space for the task at hand.  Since the lines you're combining are one after the other, working within the pattern space is simplest.  Now, if you wanted to work with data that's split up across the file (e.g. take a heading and insert it into multiple subsequent lines, making use of the hold space would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The bracket expression `[[:xdigit:]]` matches any of the *text* characters `01234567890abcdefABCDEF`. That's the reason it *appears* to match using what you tried - because there are "e", "a", "1", "2" and "0" characters in those lines. If you wanted to match any non-printing character, you could use `[[:cntrl:]]`. However, to specifically match a newline, you can use `\n`, `\x0a`, `\o12` or `\d10`.

***However,*** that's not really what you want to do since `sed` doesn't see the newline at the end of each line. It only sees them if they're embedded in lines that it appends together.

Here's a `sed` command that appends the lines together that you want:

```
sed '/Model-Manufacturer:/{N;s/\n//}' myfile
```

Explanation:

- `/Model-Manufacturer:/{` - If a line matches "Model-Manufacturer:"

  - `N` - Append the next line
  - `s/\n//` - Remove the embedded newline added by the append operation
- `}` - end if

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your code. sed '/Model-Manufacturer: *$/N;s/\n//'. My approach with `xdigit` was nonsensical given that all characters are hex, as you explained.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use awk

```
gawk '/Model/{printf $0;getline;print;next}1' file
```

Comment: Watch out using printf on user input this will break if `$0` contains `%s` or
similar. Instead use `printf "%s" "$0"`